# How to keep files number of files inmemory and pass them to multiprocessing in python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have to merge number of CSV files into one CSV. Currently I write all csv files in a folder and then pass them to Multiprocessing to make them in a single CSV file.

```
 def transform():
        ......
        transform = etree.XSLT(xslt)
        result = transform(elem)
        writeOutput(result) //--->writes csv files to outputdir(i want to do this inmemory)

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(max_threads)
    list_of_csvs=[]
    outputdir = 'output/'
    for csvFile in glob(outputdir + '*.csv'):
        list_of_csvs.append(csvFile)
    pool.map(writeToSingleCSV, list_of_csvs)
    pool.close()
```

Without writing each and every CSV file into the outputdir, how can I keep that inmemory and pass that to  **pool.map()**?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but a pointer. It is highly likely you're not going to get any benefits from multiprocessing with this. You are far more likely to be IO bound (i.e. reading/writing files), than CPU bound (moving a bit of memory around). Take out the multiprocessing. It's not faster in this case, and makes your code a lot more complicated.

Comment: consider using a `multiprocessing.Manager()` object to store your results (create a fake `list` object from it). then maybe you have to sort the data and write it back